# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\pi^2(\frac{n^2}{a^2})t}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, spectral-theory

I have to compute $$Z(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda_nt}$$ with $\lambda_n=\pi^2\left(\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}\right)$. So 
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\pi^2\left(\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}\right)\right)t=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\pi^2\left(\frac{m^2}{a^2}\right)t\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\pi^2\left(\frac{n^2}{b^2}\right)t\right)$$

where $a$, $b$ are real constants and $t$ a real variable.

$$e^{-tn^2}\le\int_{n-1}^n e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n-1)^2}$$ and $$e^{-t(n+1)^2}\le\int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n)^2}$$

so we obtain $$\int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n)^2} \le\int_{n-1}^n e^{-tx^2} \implies \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2}\le \sum_{n \geq 1}e^{-t(n)^2} \le\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2}$$
However, I cannot find explicitly the value $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\pi^2\left(\frac{n^2}{a^2}\right)t\right)$$ However, this does not give me an explicit solution on the convergence of $Z(t)$.

Could anyone could help me on how to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\pi^2\left(\frac{n^2}{a^2}\right)t\right)$?

Comment: For any non-zero $t > 0$ (assume $t$ is some sort of time that is $+ve$), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(\pi^2\left(\frac{n^2}{a^2}\right)t\right)$ diverges. Rather than editing will leave it to you to change, just in case it was what you meant.

Comment: The sum is not $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(\pi^2\left(\frac{n^2}{a^2}\right)t\right)$, it is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(-\pi^2\left(\frac{n^2}{a^2}\right)t\right)$, and cannot diverge because of the minus.

Comment: The answer was already given on the other page (yes, in the answer you *did not* accept...), so why repost the same question?

Comment: I was looking at the title